# Fear of DataBinding

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am newBie while I know the concept of dataadapters, dataset,tables and controls I have a initial fear of databinding. Is there a very simple code explaining it very deeply to understand the concept as well?
My Fears are that:
1- When I want to have a gridview and this should be binded to my dataset so eg user opens a combo in column and there are updated information on a field of a table in my dataset.
2- When I want to apply the changes from my database to my dataset
3- When After refreshing the dataset the controls should be filled with new information now!

Comment: WPF, WinForms, WebForms? All those are diametraly different.

Answer (score 2):

There is a WPF data binding cheat sheet at http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf[3](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)

You sould also read these CodeProject articles:

[WPF Data Binding - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataBinding1.aspx)

[A Guided Tour of WPF – Part 3 (Data binding)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_3.aspx)

Comment: You didn't include the later two links well.

Comment: @František Žiačik I think with that rep you can not add links.

Answer (score 0):

I would just look at these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzx4e13.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w7ya1ts.aspx

One thing to remember with gridview is it's an ASP control...so when you postback the information stored in it remains....while the dataset you got in the code behind is gone and you have to re-fetch it.